# Angularjs filter: get attribute 'name' by ID

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

In html I have the following.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Select a plate:</label>
       <div class="col-sm-5">
            <select class="form-control m-b-sm" id="plateId" ng-change="getSelectedPlate(selectedPlate.item)" ng-model="selectedPlate.item" ng-options="plate as (plate.id + ' - ' + plate.serial_number) for plate in plates" required="true" />
                <option value=" ">----------</option>
             </select>
        </div>
 </div>
```

upon selection of a plate. I have ng-model which retrieves the plate-type id as well.

```
 <div class="form-group">
      <label for="input-readonly" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Project Name: </label>
      <div class="col-sm-5">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input-readonly" value="{{selectedPlate.item.plate_types_id.name}}" readonly>
      </div>
 </div>
```

Now all I want is instead of showing the `plate_types_id` is to show the name of the plate type.

I am new to angularjs and unable to figure this simple thing out. Any help would me much appreciated.

Comment: How about `value="{{selectedPlate.item.name}}"`

Comment: @asdf_enel_hak This won't work. I have tried this already. I first need the plate_type_id (which is another table in DB) and than retrieve the name attribute in by using the ID

Comment: You mind involving us in that, i suppose, server side code? Or is it possible to load the name into the model as well?

Comment: @Lacrioque I am sorry if I am not making the question as clear as possible. But it's real simple. When A plate is selected ( the first above mentioned html) than underneath it pops up ( the second html - readonly ) the `platetype` which has the plate_type_id of that selected plate. Now Instead of the `ID` I want the name  of the plate_type ... So something like this.   `{{selectedPlate.item.plate_type_id.name}}`

Comment: What is your `plate` object structure and can you show `getSelectedPlate` function ? Probably you need a database call inside `getSelectedPlate` method !

Comment: Try consoling out the model and see if the name is in there and if not, try to put it into model generation.